# Inside of Worker class call BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-workmanager

As for my requirement I would like to call inside of Worker class call `BroadcastReceiver` class , any one please give some suggestions.

```
// BroadcastReceiver sample class 
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("??????","Working fine");
    }
}


// workers class 
class WorkSample(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :  Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {

       // BroadcastReceiver class
         NetworkChangeReceiver()

         return Result.success()
     }

 }


//Activity  
button.setOnClickListener {
     // request of workmanager 
     val constraints  = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

     val OneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkSample::class.java).setConstraints(constraints).build()
     WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call inside of `doWork()` method ,

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
     val i = Intent(applicationContext, NetworkChangeReceiver::class.java)
     applicationContext.sendBroadcast(i)

     return Result.success()
}
```

Comment: Thank you  for replying , i will try this solution.